# Upload file to google drive using api with phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-drive-api

Correct me if I am wrong but as per the FAQs which I went through, I read that the javascript client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs is used only for web applications. I am making a mobile app using phonegap wherein a user should be able to upload a picture to google drive. I am going through these links:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

An as you can see, it uses javascript client library for uploading the file. Is there a way I can do it without using that library. If so how can I do using pure js or jquery?

Thanks

---

Thanks JunYoung ... I was able to finish the part where in you log in and authorize. Now what I am trying to do is upload a file to my Drive. All the examples that I see use the JS client library. https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js      I want to execute the same but without the use of gapi.client.request . I want to use simple POST. Here is my code

```
          const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
          const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
          const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

          var reader = new FileReader();
          var fileContent = this.$.fileInput.getFiles()[0];
          reader.readAsBinaryString(fileContent);
          reader.onload = function(e) {
              var contentType = fileContent.type || 'application/octet-stream';
              var metadata = {
              'title': fileContent.name,
              'mimeType': contentType
              };
              var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
              var multipartRequestBody =
              delimiter +
              'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' + JSON.stringify(metadata) + delimiter + 'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' + 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' + '\r\n' + base64Data + close_delim;

              var driveAjax = new enyo.Ajax({
                     url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files',
                     method: 'POST',
                     contentType: 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"',
                     postBody: multipartRequestBody
                  });
              driveAjax.response(this, "uploadSuccess");
              driveAjax.error(this, "processError");
              driveAjax.go({
                    uploadType:'multipart'
              });
```

As you can see I have replaced the gapi.client.request part with simple ajax call. But this doesn't seem to work. BTW I am using enyo js framework. Can you spot any issues with this?

Comment: You can check my answer on a similar SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746756/how-implement-google-drive-in-ionic-app/42412306) in case you are still having issues with integrating google drive to your cordova app

Answer (score 2):

Was there any problem integrating Drive API with Phonegap?

Drive API is basically HTTP requests and it can all be done with pure Javascript. Therefore, you can use jQuery AJAX calls for Files.insert(). However, I would recommend you to use Javascript client. Here is an example of [OAuth using JS client library](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent). Please try this example with your Phonegap application and ask question again if there is any problem.

Comment: Thanks JunYoung ... I was able to finish the part where in you log in and authorize. Now what I am trying to do is upload a file to my Drive. All the examples that I see use the JS client library. https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js

Comment: Seems link is out of date. Drive javaScript QuickStart is here as of 3/14/2016: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js