# how implement google drive in ionic app

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, ionic-framework, google-drive-api

i need to connect my ionic app to google drive, show all the files, and maybe upload, download,delete, edit.So I try this
https://github.com/Raza-Dar/ionic-google-drive2

errors: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) [https://apis.google.com/*/scs/apps-static/*/js/k=oz.gapi.en.RArmLpCIYB0.O/m](https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en.RArmLpCIYB0.O/m)…1/ed=1/am=QQ/rs=AGLTcCOEiG2RgKkKDvOG7y5PZ-fMFMsJXQ/t=zcms/cb=gapi.loaded_01

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'load' of undefined

Could not find InAppBrowser plugin

and this
http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/1
no errors on console...but after authentication return to the main page

and this
http://excellencenodejsblog.com/cordova-ionic-google-oauth-login-for-your-mobile-app/
with this i get the info of the users but not the file in drive

any suggestion?Please i need some working example starter code
Thank you

Answer (score 7):

You need to authenticate natively your cordova application with Google in order to make use of the APIs. Firstly follow the official Google guides for each platform (iOS and Android) if you haven't already, to create the required credentials for your application. Then try the plugin on the link below:

[Cordova google drive plugin](https://github.com/JcDenton86/cordova-plugin-jc-googledrive)

I created this plugin for a personal mobile project. This plugin supports upload,download and list of files.

To retrieve a list of files created/uploaded by your application for Android you can try this on Java side:

```
private void fileList() {
    Query query = new Query.Builder().addFilter(Filters.and(
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "application/octet-stream"),
            Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false))).build();

    Drive.DriveApi.query(mGoogleApiClient, query)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        mCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR,"failed to retrieve file list"));
                        return;
                    }
                    MetadataBuffer flist = result.getMetadataBuffer();
                    Log.i(TAG,flist.get(0).getClass().getName());
                    JSONArray response = new JSONArray();
                    for (Metadata file: flist
                         ) {
                        try {
                            response.put(new JSONObject().put("name", file.getTitle()).put("created", file.getCreatedDate().toString()).put("id", file.getDriveId().toString()));
                        }catch (JSONException ex){ex.getMessage();}
                    }
                    JSONObject flistJSON = new JSONObject();
                    try{
                        flistJSON.put("flist", response);
                    } catch (JSONException ex){}
                    mCallbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,flistJSON));
                    flist.release();
                    //Log.i(TAG,flist.toString());
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a valuable Cordova plugin. Is this plugin has a build-in authentication process? For the android platform where I have to use the OAuth client id in your plugin installation side (android). Here is an issue about my problem on your repo: https://github.com/JcDenton86/cordova-plugin-jc-googledrive/issues/32

Answer (score 4):

Did you correctly create a project for your application on Google Developer Console? Enabled Google Drive API ? Configured your credentials and authentication view to work with your application ? 
Ok well, using any endpoint of Google Api, will bring you through 2 steps:

1. **Log the user using your api key and scopes needed**, if success you will get **an access_token to be able to use the API for an hour** : in your case prefer use $cordovaOauth.google(YOUR_API_KEY,YOUR_SCOPES), the scope is an array of permissions like ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] which, in this case, means "APPName require to manage(crud) your files"
2. **Make the request needed using the access token and your api key**, for example to create a folder:

   ```
   $http.post(
      'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files&access_token='+ACCESS_TOKEN,
       {
          title:"FolderName",
          mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder", // special mimeType for google drive folders
          key: YOUR_API_KEY
       }
   ).success(function (data) {
       console.log(data.id); // id of the created folder
       console.log(data.alternateLink); // Web link to created folder
   }).catch(function(err){
       console.log(err); 
   })
   ```

   The url used https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files, is for metadatas requests, to upload you will prefer https://www.googleapis.com/**upload**/drive/v2/files, for more documentation go there https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations

Do never forget that ngCordova features works only on device or emulator, and not in the browser/navigator.

Comment: thank you so so so so much ... really thank you. I'll try as soon as possible. But yes i think that i have configurated all in the right way in google console

Comment: You are welcome, and certainly lucky because i'm working on it for a Project and i already faced every problem of this part. I have a working angular service if needed

Comment: oh boss...you're amazing. If you can give me a link to an example code of a working app that use google drive to show, download and upload files it will be great because i have some other issues. Expecially if is a ionic project. Anyway thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Jean can i send you my app, my code? because i can't understood my errors. Sorry for annoying you, but you are the only one that answer me.

Comment: Here is a gist where you can find a working example for authenticating to google api using $cordovaOauth, you will be ready with the access_token for further API call and use authenticate() method again if token has expired. https://gist.github.com/jeansaigne/fd577e0f040bc3621cc0#file-ionic-service-google-api-localstorage-js

Comment: @JeanSaigne What should I do with ionic2? I got a access_token.But when I try http.post in ionic2, it return 404 OK for URL

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to upload the sqlite backup to google drive?