# How to upload any file to google drive using cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-drive-api, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I'm implementing the google drive integration to upload the file in google drive using my cordova/phonegap file transfer api.
I want to use following  Google rest API (multipart rest api )with phonegap file transfer API
 https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

So Please Guide me to do the same
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Everything you need to know can be find in the documentation you might want to start there. Have you looked at the examples for JavaScript? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples. If you have a specific questions you can ask again :)

Comment: you can check my answer on similar SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746756/how-implement-google-drive-in-ionic-app/42412306#42412306)