# ionic 2 How to download file from Google Drive and I-cloud

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, icloud

I am working on a chat application and I want to add attachment functionality in my App.

I want to attach every kind of file from Google Drive and I-Cloud ??

I have tried many thing but they all didn't worked I Tried  doing it with 
"[how implement google drive in ionic app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746756/how-implement-google-drive-in-ionic-app)" (It didn't worked).
I tried it with cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-jc-googledrive" But I think it does not support IONIC 2

My app Is based on IONIC-2 and Angular-2. Can some one suggest me a way to attach file from drive and I-cloud.
Can someone Please suggest me a way to do so.

Thanks!!

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/transfer/

Comment: I have tried this one as well .. No luck ..

Comment: can place your code so that let me check

Comment: fileTransfer.download(self.fileUri, self.folderPath+"/").then((entry) => {
                                            alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
                                        }, (error) => {
                                            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                                        });

I am using "FileChooser" Plugin to choose file and It gives me file Uri.
When I use this it gives me error .. "unable to Resolve" Error code "0"

Comment: `fileTransfer.download(self.fileUri, this.file.externalDataDirectory+ "yourfilename")` try this  you have to install both file and transfer plugin

Comment: I have done Both of them. Let me try using filename as well.

Comment: I get this "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DQBOPPWTmvTL3yktxCf8_dAPtfxdx0BZkgh3h_Sr14KO0voIi%0A" as file Uri.

Is there any way to get the file type of this file. Because the downloaded file will not open without extension.

Comment: `encodeURI(self.fileUri)` and try

Comment: I tried it. But it does not work.  It return me the same file Uri.
 var encodefileURI = encodeURI(self.fileUri);
fileTransfer.download(encodefileURI,self.folderPath+"/"+self.fileName).then((entry) => { alert('download complete: ' + entry.toURL()); 
}, (error) => {});

and Gives me error "Unable to resolve filesystem path"

Comment: `fileTransfer.download(encodefileURI+self.folderPath+self‌​.fileName)`

Comment: Hello 
Good Morning 

I am also using the same thing " fileTransfer.download(encodefileURI, self.folderPath+self.fileName)"  Same error :(

Comment: send me your `encodefileURI` link i will check

Comment: My encodefileURI "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%253DYDTSO09t9YwiDYMsUohgbdOWk62PqL4AsQrRNxSNZtl0iPjU%250A"

Comment: encodefileuri is wrong

Comment: I have used this
var encodefileURI = encodeURI(self.fileUri);
console.log(encodefileURI);

It gives me this URI in console

Comment: `console.log(self.fileUri)` what it gives send me here

Comment: console.log(self.fileUri) = "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3DYDTSO09t9YwiDYMsUohgbdOWk62PqL4AsQrRNxSNZtl0iPjU%0A"




console.log(encodefileURI) = "content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%253DYDTSO09t9YwiDYMsUohgbdOWk62PqL4AsQrRNxSNZtl0iPjU%250A"


These are the two consoles that I get

Comment: Any Luck @MohanGopi

Comment: i told you the url is wrong copy that url and past it in browser if it is able to render something like viewing or downloading then we can think about it

Comment: I am getting this file URI on choosing file from drive by "file chooser" plugin. Is there any alternate way to get the file URI @MohanGopi