# Ionic 2: Uploading file from google drive/cloud to my own server

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

In my application  I have a functionality where user can upload his resume(of format .doc,.docx,.pdf). I'm using Ionic File Choosing [plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-chooser/) to choose the file and to upload  I'm using Ionic File Transfer [plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/). It is known that the file transfer plugin expects fileName filed in FileUploadOptions which will be the name of file to be uploaded with it's extension. In my case say resume.pdf/doc/docx.

1. For getting the file extension I'm passing the chosen file's path to Ionic File Path [plugin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path/) which will resolve it to it's native path.
2. The whole process is working absolutely fine when the file is chosen from mobile's native file system.
3. But when the file is chosen from drive/cloud application the Ionic File Path plugin throws error cannot be resolved to native path.
4. As I'm not able to resolve file path  to  it's native path I'm not getting file's extension.
5. When I'm not aware of file's extension it is not possible to upload the file to my server. (if I keep filename field empty in FileUploadOptions, by default name.jpg will be taken which may not be the type of file that I'm trying to upload).
6. Please suggest how can I get the extension of file that is chosen from drive or how can I upload a file without default filename field in FileUploadOptions.
   7.It's similar to this question [ionic 2 How to download file from Google Drive and I-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44624421/ionic-2-how-to-download-file-from-google-drive-and-i-cloud) as there is no proper answer for this question I'm reposting it with further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for this problem. I have created a public  github gist where I have explained the solution. The link for it is as below
https://gist.github.com/coolvasanth/d042a26deda75f5e390b42b87995f30d